# Find the series expansion of $\text{csch}^{-1}(x)$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the series expansion of $\text{csch}^{-1}(x)$
$\text{csch}^{-1}(x)=\ln 2-\ln x+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{3}{32}x^4+\frac{5}{96}x^6-...$

---

$\text{csch}^{-1}(x)=\ln(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{1}{x})$
$=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+\frac{1}{x})=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{x})=\ln(1+\sqrt{x^2+1})-\ln x$
$=(x^2+1)^{1/2}-\frac{x^2+1}{2}+\frac{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{(x^2+1)^2}{4}+...-\ln x$
Now using binomial theorem for rational exponents
$=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{8}x^4+...-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{8}x^4+...)-\frac{1}{4}(x^4+2x^2+1)+....-\ln x$

I know that $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...=\ln 2$
But $x^2,x^4$ terms i am not able to get with correct coefficients,they gets cancelled out from the previous binomial expansion terms.
Have i made some mistake in this.Or this method is not ok.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The series expansion at what center? Surely not at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand $~\text{arccsch}'(x)=-\dfrac1{|x|\sqrt{1+x^2}}~$ into its [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then integrate term

by term. **P.S. :** And don't forget the constant of integration, which, in this case, is not zero. :-$)$

Answer (score 2):

Do the calculations as follows. First,
$$
1+\sqrt{1+x^2}=2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}x^{2k},\quad|x|<1.
$$
Then
$$
\ln\bigl(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\bigr)=\ln2+\ln\Bigr(1+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}x^{2k}\Bigl),\quad|x|<1.
$$
Finally, use the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$.